# Relative orders of an element with respect to a subgroup

Tags: group-theory

There is a theorem in an old monograph:

> **Theorem 1.** A pair of subgroups $A$ and $B$ forms a distributive pair if and only if for every element $c$ of $A\vee B$, not in $A$ nor in $B$, its relative orders with respect to $A$ and $B$ are finite and relatively prime to each other.

$A\vee B$ is the subgroup generated by $A$ and $B$.

What does *relative orders with respect to $A$ and $B$* mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the relative order of $c$ with respect to $A$ is the minimal $n>0$ for which $c^n\in A$.

For normal subgroups this coincides with the order of $c$'s residue in the quotient group.

Comment: seems reasonable. the order itself is the relative order wrt $\{1\}$.